# How to target current "stage" of fullpage.js using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

How can I target the current "stage" of **[fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)** ? Meaning - how can I tell jQuery to detect the fourth stage that I have added a class of `"homeFour"` to?

Here is my markup:

```
    <div id="fullpage" style="height: 100%; position: relative;" class="fullpage-wrapper">
        <div class="section homeOne fp-section fp-table" style="height: 915px;"><div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:915px;">
        </div></div>
        <div class="section homeTwo fp-section fp-table" style="height: 915px;"><div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:915px;">
        </div></div>
        <div class="section homeThree fp-section fp-table" style="height: 915px;"><div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:915px;">Section Three</div></div>
        <div class="section homeFour fp-section fp-table active fp-completely" style="height: 915px;"><div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:915px;">Section Four</div></div>
    </div>
```

What I need to do is, tell jQuery that WHEN the `section fp-section fp-table active fp-completely` has a class of homeFour like so - `section homeFour fp-section fp-table active fp-completely` to do something else?

So far it activates when I load the page and does not function as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterLoad (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
        if($(".homeFour").is(".active")){
            // Do stuff
        }
    },
    //...
});
```

Comment: It does not work for me. Am I supposed to change anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex to something?

Comment: @Sqnkov Sorry, could you please try it now, here's a JSFiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/55jbLxvc/1/

Comment: @Sqnkov And no, you don't have to change the values.

Comment: Last fiddle nailed it. Thank You very much! :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: Is there a possibility to add other conditionals for the other stages as well?