# fullpage.js init event between stages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I have a page with fullpage.js functionality and I want to manipulate a page element between the stages , e.g. > during the scroll between stages.

Here is the base structure of the plugin, plus my element that I want to interact with on stage change. Right now I have achieved what I want, but it dissapears ***when*** the page reaches the fourth stage section, but I need it to dissapear ***before*** the plugin reaches the fourth section when scrolling down in the third.

```
<div id="element">
  <p>The Element. *</p>
</div>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">SECTION ONE *</div>
  <div class="section">SECTION TWO **</div>
  <div class="section">SECTION THREE ***</div>
  <div class="section homeFour">SECTION FOUR ****</div>
</div>
```

I have put together a sample ***[Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/x7bdwynx/)***

How can I achieve what I am trying to achieve?

---

**Bonus Tip:**

> *You can find the reverse logic that I have described in the second paragraph* **[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460928/how-to-target-current-stage-of-fullpage-js-using-jquery)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you need something like, onLeave event? 
https://jsfiddle.net/x7bdwynx/1/

```
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
        if(index==3&&nextIndex==4&&direction=="down")
        {        
            $('#element').addClass('hideCont');        
        }
        if(index==4&&nextIndex==3&&direction=="up")
        {        
          $('#element').removeClass('hideCont');        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Guess I am having a bit of a burnout here. Why didn't I thought of that. Thank You very much!